# Building multiple path of a DAG using a function which returns another chain of tasks

Tags: airflow

Somehow I can't get the graph right for my DAG. If I have a DAG definition like so:

```py
with models.DAG(
    'foo_21',
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *', # Every day at 5:00
    default_args={'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 27),},
) as dag:
    def sub_chain(name):
        o1 = DummyOperator(task_id=f'o1_{name}')
        o2 = DummyOperator(task_id=f'o2_{name}')
        o3 = DummyOperator(task_id=f'o3_{name}')

        return o1 >> o2 >> o3
    
    o0 = DummyOperator(task_id=f'o0')
    oZ = DummyOperator(task_id=f'oZ')

    o0 >> [sub_chain('A'), sub_chain('B')] >> oZ
```

It renders like this:

[image]

But I would expect something like

```
o0 +-> o1_A -> o2_A -> o3_A --> oZ
   |                         ^
   +-> o1_B -> o2_B -> o3_B -+
```

I don't see the mistake. Is it that we can't build task sub chains using a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `return o1 >> o2 >> o3` is problematic

- I doubt that you can chain the tasks together and return them simultaneously
- More clearly, the expression `o1 >> o2 >> o3` has a wierd type as per this screenshot (credits `IntelliJ IDEA`) [this type-inferred by IDE could be wrong, still i don't have a good feeling about it]

  [image]

---

Just slight modification in your script should get this working *(untested snippet)*

```
from typing import Tuple
from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow import models
import datetime

with models.DAG(
        'foo_21',
        schedule_interval='0 0 * * *', # Every day at 5:00
        default_args={'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 27),},
) as dag:
    def sub_chain(name):
        o1: DummyOperator = DummyOperator(task_id=f'o1_{name}')
        o2: DummyOperator = DummyOperator(task_id=f'o2_{name}')
        o3: DummyOperator = DummyOperator(task_id=f'o3_{name}')
        # chain the tasks together
        o1 >> o2 >> o3
        # return only the first and last task of the chain
        return (o1, o3)

    o0: DummyOperator = DummyOperator(task_id=f'o0')
    oZ: DummyOperator = DummyOperator(task_id=f'oZ')

    # prepare chains of tasks
    chain_a_begin_end_task_pair: Tuple[BaseOperator, BaseOperator] = sub_chain('A')
    chain_b_begin_end_task_pair: Tuple[BaseOperator, BaseOperator] = sub_chain('B')

    # connect begin tasks with oO
    o0 >> [chain_a_begin_end_task_pair[0], chain_b_begin_end_task_pair[0]]
    # connect end tasks with oZ
    [chain_a_begin_end_task_pair[1], chain_b_begin_end_task_pair[1]] >> oZ
```

Comment: I did something similar and it works.